# Circular/auto reference in Symfony 2 and Doctrine 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

how would you create a relationship of an entity with itself? I have a "SupportTicket" entity that i would like to have a "depends" field, which is a dependency on another "SupportTicket" entity. How can i create this circular reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Doctrine 2 one to one self referencing association](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-self-referencing) is your friend :)

Comment: I receive "You don't have access to this version." when going to that link.

Comment: Updated link: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-self-referencing